# Spring Boot Repository Returns the same value

Tags: spring-boot, repeat

Controller.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/customers/")
@Api(value = "account", description = "Operations pertaining to account operations")
public class AccountController {

    private final AccountService accountService;

    public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "accounts/{CIFs}")
    public Response getAccountByCIF(@PathVariable String CIFs) {
         return Response.ok().setData(accountService.findByCustomerNumberIn(CIFs));
    }

}
```

AccountRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountView, String> {

    List<AccountView> getByCustomerNumber(String cif);

    List<AccountView> getByCustomerNumberIn(List<String> cifList);

}
```

AccountService.java

```
public interface AccountService {
    
    List<AccountDto> findByCustomerNumber(String cifList);
    
    List<AccountDto> findByCustomerNumberIn(String cifList);
}
```

AccountServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountMapper accountMapper;

    public AccountServiceImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<AccountDto> findByCustomerNumber(String cif) {

        List<AccountView> account = accountRepository.getByCustomerNumber(cif);

        System.out.println(account);

        if (!account.isEmpty()) {
             return accountMapper.toAccountDtoList(account).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<AccountDto> findByCustomerNumberIn(String cifList) {
        List<String> cif = Arrays.asList(cifList.split(","));

        List<AccountView> account = accountRepository.getByCustomerNumberIn(cif);

        System.out.println(account);

        if (!account.isEmpty()) {
            return accountMapper.toAccountDtoList(account).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

When I run the application although the database have different records

it return the same value over again and again .

This is  the json outcome. For queried customer there are 6 record in the database, but the endpoint return 6 same record as above.

```
    {
        "name": "ACDESC33811018409238803204",
        "customer_number": "9238803",
        "account_number": "33811018409238803204",
        "book_ACC": "33811018409238803204",
        "account_branch": {
            "branch_number": "204",
            "branch_name": "MERKEZI FILIAL"
        },
        "balance": 88.45,
        "currency": "USD",
        "status": "NORM",
        "class": "33811",
        "open_date": "2006-05-26",
        "location": null,
        "ibanrgd": "AZ16IBAZ33811018409238803204",
        "expcat": "GENERAL",
        "user_defined_fields": [],
        "type": "S",
        "number": "2388030001",
        "start_tod_limit_date": null,
        "end_tod_limit_date": null,
        "tod_limit_Interest": null,
        "tod_limit_amount": null,
        "tod_limit_total_amount": null
    },
```

AccountMapper.java

```
package az.iba.ms.account.dto.mapper;

import az.iba.ms.account.dto.model.AccountBranchDto;
import az.iba.ms.account.dto.model.AccountDto;
import az.iba.ms.account.dto.model.FieldDto;
import az.iba.ms.account.dto.model.UserDefinedFieldsDto;
import az.iba.ms.account.entity.AccountView;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class AccountMapper {

    public List<AccountDto> toAccountDtoList(List<AccountView> accountViews) {

        return accountViews.stream()
                .map(accountView -> toAccountDto(accountView))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static AccountDto toAccountDto(AccountView account) {
        return new AccountDto()
                .setName(account.getName())
                .setCustomerNumber(account.getCustomerNumber())
                .setAccountNumber(account.getAccountNumber())
                .setBookACC(account.getBookACC())
                .setAccountBranch(new AccountBranchDto( account.getBranchCode(), account.getBranchName()))
                .setBalance(account.getBalance())
                .setCurrency(account.getCurrency())
                .setStatus(account.getStatus())
                .set_class(account.get_class())
                .setOpenDate(account.getOpenDate())
                .setLocation(account.getLocation())
                .setIbanRgd(account.getIbanRgd())
                .setExpcat(account.getExpcat())
                .setUser_defined_fields(null ) //           UserDefinedFieldsDto[] = new FieldDto(account.getFieldValue(),account.getFieldName() ))
                .setAccType(account.getAccType())
                .setNumber(account.getNumber())
                .setTodLimitStartDate(account.getTodLimitStartDate())
                .setTodLimitEndDate(account.getTodLimitEndDate())
                .setTodLimitInterest(account.getTodLimitInterest())
                .setTodLimitAmount(account.getTodLimitAmount())
                .setTodLimitTotalAmount(account.getTodLimitTotalAmount());
    }

}
```

Comment: It should be findBy instead of getBy

Comment: Show implementation of `AccountMapper`, I guess there's something wrong with `accountMapper.toAccountDtoList(account)`

Comment: @AlexpandiyanChokkan it maked no difference

Comment: @zfChaos actually i though about it . so i put System.out.println(account) to both classes. Both beginning of the mapper class and serviceImpl class. ServiceImplementation class returns the same value

Comment: So I think it'll be wrong configuration of hibernate mapping and primary key in DB.